# What does Dictionary<string, /> mean?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I ran across this construct in an online tutorial:

```
Dictionary<string, /> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, />();
```

I hadn't seen this syntax before and wasn't sure what it meant. I am not even certain that it is valid syntax at all as I can't get it to compile on my own.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial?  Context may help.

Comment: Matt, your intuition is right... it's not valid syntax. The forward slash character cannot be part of any valid type name.

Comment: Could the `/` really have been an italic uppercase letter *I*?

Comment: The tutorial or description I saw was here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42997/NET-4-0-FAQ-Part-1-The-DLR#What%20are%20the%20advantages%20and%20disadvantage%20of%20dynamic%20keyword

Comment: Is this a template of some sort? It does not look like a valid syntax to me. Your inability to compile it only confirms my suspicions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matt, your intuition is right... it's not valid syntax.  The forward slash character cannot be part of any valid type name.

After looking at the tutorial in question, and the way the dictionary is used, it looks like the definition should be `Dictionary<string, object>`.    Perhaps some strange formatting bug occurred when the code was posted to CodeProject.

Comment: @tcoder My bad.  After adding the second paragraph, does it qualify better as an answer?